# Vincular elementos HTML

Tags: javascript, html, drag-n-drop

Estou tentando fazer um projetinho só pra aprender mais sobre *HTML5*, *CSS3* e *Javascript*. Nesse projeto tenho uma `div` que é tipo um `panel` e uma outra `div` que seria um quadrado que eu iria colocar dentro desse `panel`. Estou usando o *drag and drop* para poder arrastar esses elementos pela tela.

Minha pergunta é: como que poderia fazer para quando eu colocar a `div` dentro do `panel` ela se vincular a ele e quando eu tentar arrastar o `panel`, eu arraste ele e a `div`? E também esse panel se ajustar automaticamente ao tamanho da `div`?

Isso acontece no site da [scrumwise](http://www.scrumwise.com/)...

O código que já tenho é esse aqui:

## panel

```
 <div class="panel panel-success" id="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Qualquer texto</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

            </div>
 </div>
```

## Div

```
<div style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: black;" id="div">

</div>
```

## O javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#panel").draggable();
        $("#div").draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Outra coisa, estou usando o *bootstrap* também!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhe [**esse exemplo que fiz no JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/4n19eq1q/1/).

O javascript foi esse:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#panel").draggable();
  $(".div").draggable();
  $("#panel").droppable({
    accept: ".div",
    drop: function() {
      $(this).css({
        background: "red",
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        display: "inline-block"
      });
      $(".panel .panel-body").css({
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto"
      });
      $('.div').draggable('destroy');
      $('.div').appendTo(".panel .panel-body");
      $('.div').css({
        position: "relative",
        left: 0,
        top: 0
      });
    },
    hoverClass: "hover"
  });
})
```

Primeiramente, defino a `div.div` e a `div#panel` com o `.draggable()`. Após isso uso o [`.droppable`](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) no `#panel`, para que seja possível o `drop`.

O `.droppable` recebe como argumento, um objeto que tem as seguintes chaves:

- **accept -** elemento aceitável no momento de `drag`.
- **drop -** callback para ser chamado após o `drop down`.
- **hoverClass -** class acionada no momento do `drag`.

O callback do `drop`, faço com que a `div#panel` se ajuste ao elemento "solto",

e faço um `.draggable('destroy')` na `.div` para que não seja mais possível arrastá-la. Depois adiciono essa `div` a `div.panel-body`, do seu `#panel`. E mudo um pouco do css da `.div` para que ela não fique mau ajustada.

No `hoverClass` uso apenas um tracejado, para a marcação do *drag*.

O resto do *css* você pode ver no *fiddle*, é bem simples.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Muito bom! Teria uma outra coisa que eu queria te perguntar... Ao estilo do que ocorre no site do scrumwise, teria como eu criar uma div, no mesmo estilo que fez, e salvar o estado da div? Porque da forma que ta, se eu der um f5, as divs são desvinculadas...

Comment: @ÉrikThiago obrigado. Bem, isso seria algo mais complicado.. já que teria um backend, ou no mínimo um salvamento em storage. Fiz só o front-end pelo que estava na pergunta. Caso queira algo mais "sofisticado" seria o caso de fazer outra pergunta relacionada.

Comment: Então eu vou fazer! Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: @ÉrikThiago, estou preparando, um modelo bem simples com `localStorage`, apenas para ilustrar, quando terminar, posto..

Comment: ok! Já [criei a pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109873/salvar-estado-ap%C3%B3s-vincular-elementos-html).

Comment: @ÉrikThiago, muito bom.. agora é só aguardar... :) Mas teria mais algo que teria dúvida em relação ao front-end?

Comment: Ah, tenho dúvidas em relação ao sistema de grids do bootstrap. Porque queria colocar tipo uma ao lado da outra e tudo mais... Mas de acordo com o tempo vou aprendendo mais! E cara, muito obrigado mesmo pela disposição e por ajudar a conseguir resolver!

Comment: @ÉrikThiago, de nada cara. Fico feliz em ter ajudado :) . Mas se a reposta serviu perfeitamente, você pode "aceitar" ela, assim saberão que o problema, pelo menos dessa pergunta, foi resolvido.

Comment: Ah tinha esquecido! Só se for agora!